# How to trigger a "click" event on an invisible button in IE9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-9

Because of some very weird authorization problems, my CSS (or something) gets messed up and I can't see my button (<a..> anchor actually). I am using IE9 and don't have the option of using something else. As far as I see JQuery 1.10.2 is loaded.

I'm not very interested in seeing my button, just in clicking on it, because I don't want to fix the CSS, I just want to access the backend (I'm not the frontend guy in this story).

My button looks like this:

```
<a onclick="js.search()" href="javascript:void(0)" id="asdf12345">Search<img class="r" src="im/arrow-gray.gif"/></a>
```

What I've tried:

- First, I entered the id manually, within the IE9 Developer tools > HTML tab. (the anchor had no id- that's why)
- Tried to invoke the "js.search()" function manually, but *js* is not defined.
- I tried using the jQuery selector for the precise ID `$('#asdf12345').trigger("click");` but it also doesn't do anything.

I'm not very experienced in the frontend, for instance I don't know why the "js" object isn't within scope in the console (cuz I can call the *alert('asdf');* function for instance, so something *does* work).

So if anyone is aware of any way in which i can call my backend, simulating a click, that would help a lot!

**[EDIT]**
After failing to trigger the *onClick* programatically, taking Alex Shilman's suggestion, I messed around with the CSS - making my fonts smaller made it so that my images fit on the screen, so I could click on them.

Comment: If it is not in the scope in the console, than there should be no way it is in scope for the link.

Comment: What makes you think that `js.search()` should be called and not just `search()`?

Comment: well the string "js.search()" makes me thing that... anyway "search()" doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the inline onclick out and create an event handler with jquery like this:

html:

```
<a id="asdf12345"> Search <img class="r" src="im/arrow-gray.gif"/></a>
```

JS:

```
 $(function(){
  $('body').on('click', '#asdf12345', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('clicked anchor');
  });
});
```

then you can do:

```
$('#asdf12345').trigger("click");
```

If you're not seeing you image on the screen, try fiddling around with the css.

Comment: doesn't do anything apparently :|

Comment: did you wrap on click with $(function(){})

Comment: Does your a id="asdf12345" get added dynamically after the page loads?

Comment: i add it by hand, in the Developer Tools. It's not dynamically in the programatical sense, but literally i add it by hand after the page loads...and it still doesn't do anything :|

Comment: OK, thats why. I edited my answer again. Make sure the html and the javascript matches exactly.

Comment: apparently my JQuery selector doesn't return anything, meaning $('#asdf12345').length == 0. i'm searching for why this is happening (oh, of course, your code didn't work, but +1 for the effort to help )

Comment: Which version of jquery are you including?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44632/discussion-between-vlad-ardelean-and-alex-shilman)